# How to fix broken android studio emulator after moving sdk directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After moving my sdk files, my android application gives following errors:

```
01:42   Emulator: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

01:42   Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=0,id=system,file=C:\Users\My\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_22.avd\system.img.qcow2,read-only,l2-cache-size=1048576: Could not open backing file: Could not open 'C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\/system.img': The system cannot find the path specified.

01:42   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is provided:

```
Could not open 'C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\/system.img'
```

Looks like it is either the path itself or the mixing of forward and backslash characters in the URI, which is invalid. Looks like this is for Windows. Java will deal with either/or but... is better to use just forward slashes (instead of Windows back-slashes as this is an escape character in strings).

Ex: `C:/Users/My/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-22/google_apis/x86/system.img`

Try verifying with a Java File instance (create a File object with a given path) by calling `{File}.canRead()` or `isFile()` for example.